# How to model reply to the message sender in BPMN

Tags: bpmn

I have a service that should reply either to consumer or to supplier to the same request - to show stock. How do I model such a service that replies to the corresponding party? Current solution - duplicating same paths for client and supplier - looks weird and does not describe what is really happening at the service side (the service is one processing system that knows who to reply)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this.

**First approach could be** to use an exclusive gateway and check the type of the message.

[image]

**Second approach**, which I personally prefer is to collapse the stock pool. An only model the client and supplier. See the following model.

[image]

Comment: thank you for reply. I can not collapse the stock pool as it is a part of processeses and collaboration that take place in other lanes. Also the first solution seems to be even more complex than just duplicating :( so it turns out theres no obvious way to model this in BPMN

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have to model (in this diagram) `supplier` and `client` as two separate entities. Just replace them with a single entity `third party` as this communication seems similar for both.

Comment: in my case the overall business process diagram is much more complicated and this is only a single part in the overall collaboration so I can not just merge the supplier and client concepts